# Storing elements in structure array of words in C

Tags: c, file, structure, text-files

I have a question about my program crashing when i try to increment to store another word in the structure array of words. The program reads each line and word correct but for some reason when i try to increment to store more words it always crashes. Any suggestions?

textFile(input):

```
OK UH UH SOUND FIELD IS UP 
OK RUNNING TEST SERIES 
OK 
SOUTHWEST SOUTHWEST CONFIRMED 
PEEN HIT CONFIRMED ARMED FIRE 
AND THAT'S TWO UM WHAT YOU WANT TO MOVE A LITTLE CLOSER 
OK 
OK 
PEEN FORE CONFIRMED ARMED 
ARMED FIRE 
THAT'S A THREE ARMED FIRE 
OH THAT'S ONLY A TWO OK 
GOING TO LASER CANNON 
BOX THAN OK I'M GOING TO GO FOR BAD CHOP CAN YOU CONFIRM BAD CHOP 
FIRE 
UH HOLD ON ARMED FIRE 
OK 
GO NEED ARMED FIRE 
THAT WAS A REPEAT HE'S MOVING OUT 
YEP YOU WANT TO GO AHEAD OF HIM 
OK 
YOU WANT TO DO A SWEEP 
SUE BID ARMED 
FIRE 
OK 
DEED NEED I'M GOING TO OK I'M GOING TO GO FOR SUE ZOO ARMED 
FIRE 
OK I'M GOING TO GO FOR DEED YEN 
DEED YEN DEED YEN 
FIRE 
OK I NEED A SWEEP
```

Structure Code:

```
typedef struct {
  char word[maxLetters];
  int  freq;
} WordArray; //struct type
```

Main Code:

```
#define maxLetters 101
#define maxWords 200
int inputReader(WordArray input[], char f[maxWords]){

// ATTRIBUTES //
int i = 0;
int uniqueWords = 0;
int contains = 0;
int numOfWords = 0;
int k = 0;

FILE *finput;
char lineOfWords[1000];

finput = fopen( f, "r");



WordArray allWords[maxWords];


while(fgets(lineOfWords, maxWords, finput) != NULL) { // reads each line of words

     // PROBLEM IS HERE
     while(fscanf(finput, "%s", allWords[numOfWords].word) == 1) // reads each word from line
     { 

        printf("%s\n", allWords[numOfWords].word);// this works
        //numOfWords++;    if i add this i receive the error 
                          // "Segmentation Error(core dumped)"


     }
}

return 0; // default ignore this
}
```

Comment: The expression `sizeof(input)` will not work as you expect, because arrays decays to pointers you are not getting the size of the array you pass to the function, you are getting the size of the pointer (which will be `4` on most 32-bit systems and `8` on most 64-bit systems). If you need the function to know the size in bytes of the arrays, you need to explicitly pass it along to the function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but that doesn't have to do with my question because im not using that variable at this point

Comment: `memset(lineOfWords, 0x00, sizeof(lineOfWords));` is not really required.

Comment: You are reading 1023 chars into an array, which is only 101 characters long (or am I wrong?)

Comment: There are also other problems, like you reading from the input file *twice*, once in the `fgets` and once in the `fscanf` (this behavior may be intended, but it looks suspicious). You aso defie `maxLetters` to be `101`, but tell `fscanf` to scan up to `1023` characters, which might write way out of bounds of the array. This leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is a very common cause for weird behaviors and crashes.

Comment: Oh and speaking of unnecessary; 0x00 is very much just 0.

Comment: Ok guys, i already checked all of those before you guys stated this and it still has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Also, im using fgets and scanf to retreieve the line first and then read each word 1 by 1 to store it into the structure(if you look at the comments it explains this)

Comment: use `sscanf` for that. Is each line one word?

Comment: No, i scan 1 line per iteration from the file and in the second while loop i scan every word in that 1 line to recieve all words

Comment: And then store each word into the WordArray structure which is my problem everything works except the operation to store into the WordArray

Comment: @geforce are the words delimited by space?

Comment: yes they are delimited by space

Comment: Can you please show a sample of the input file? One the cause the bad behavior. And also please show what parts of it should go into the structure?

Comment: Sample file is over 1000 lines but i will show some of it and i used strtok before i recoded it and still recieve that segmentation error

Comment: To clarify what iharob is trying to say: You've already read the whole line, no need to read words from the file again, you just read those into a string, get the words from this string.

Comment: If you get the segfault where you say you do, just add a simple printf that will print the value of `numOfWords` and make sure it doesn't go above `200`, if it does, you'll know why it crashes. **EDIT**: Simply put: Add code to check for boundaries and print error messages if you try to exceed them.

Comment: Run in a debugger, and when the crash happens then look at the where it happens (so you are sure it happens where you think it happens) and also check the values of all involved variables to make sure they look valid an in range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is crashing because you are not limiting the number of words read, you should add to the outer loop,

```
(numOfWords < maxWords)
```

and some other issues i've added comments on in the source code, i also fixed the double read from the file using `strtok` for the parsing part.

```
int inputReader(WordArray input[], char f[maxWords])
{
    (void) input;
    // ATTRIBUTES //
    int numOfWords = 0;

    FILE *finput;
    char lineOfWords[1000];

    finput = fopen( f, "r");

    WordArray allWords[maxWords];

    /*
     * tell fgets NOT to read more than sizeof(lineOfWords) bytes, 
     * not maxWords, they are unrelated
     */
    while ((fgets(lineOfWords, sizeof(lineOfWords), finput) != NULL) && (numOfWords < maxWords)) { // reads each line of words
        char *pointer;
        char *token;

        pointer = lineOfWords;
        /* also prevent overflowing the struct array */
        while (((token = strtok(pointer, " ")) != NULL) && (numOfWords < maxWords)) {
           /* next call to strtok for the same string requires first parameter to be NULL */
            pointer = NULL;
            /* strncpy prevent copying more than maxLetters bytes */
            strncpy(allWords[numOfWords].word, token, maxLetters - 1);
            /* ensure null terminating byte */
            allWords[numOfWords].word[maxLetters - 1] = '\0'; 

            numOfWords++;
        }
    }
    /* don't forget to close the file */
    fclose(finput);
    return 0; // default ignore this
}
```

Comment: @geforce because I forgot to set `pointer` to `NULL` in the inner `while` loop, i've fixed it.

Comment: Ok well it doesn't crash now and reads the text file but not all the words in the text file like it could before

Comment: @geforce  You need to increase `maxWords` a lot, because in average each line has 5 or 6 words and if you say there are over 1000 lines, then about 8192 would be fine i think.

Comment: well then i have to put more space in the  lineOfWords variable?

Comment: @geforce no, it has nothing to do with `lineOfWords`, it's `maxWords`

Comment: Ok well in that case the compiler is telling me something else, its outputting the same error again

Comment: i changed the condition in both while loops to "numOfWords < 8192" and it just throws the same error i cant set that variable to 8192 because there are arrays and words i made with size numOfWords

Comment: "Segmentation Error(core dumped)"

Comment: @geforce and that happened when you increased `maxWords`?

Comment: Ok i see why, i have to change size of "WordArray allWords[maxWords]" also because it copies for that size

Comment: Ok i fixed it, i have to change the size of that variable allWords to size 99999 and maxWords to 99999 to read the textFile fully

Comment: But my question is lets say if its a different text file should the size 99999 be good enough or should i make a method to count all words because it will vary on the text file?

Comment: If the file is very large, may be you need to dynamically allocate the array of structs, if it's even larger you should be careful it does not exceed the size of your system's memory, which is very unlikely but not impossible, if you want more help this is my email `iharob@gmail.com`.